# Firestore data usage

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In firestore I can have Field and Collection together in a Document. Let's say I want to fetch only the fields of a document. I will do it in the following way.

```
this.afs.collection('coll1').document('document1').ref.get().then(x=>{
  colsole.log(x.data());
});
```

Now `x.data()` is only showing me the fields only, not the collection which is correct. But in the background is it downloading all data of the document. As I don't need all the data it will be an extra data usage.

Comment: I am unsure about your question? The query is downloading the data for the document - but not the collections for that document. That is one of the biggest features of firestore, and a massive improvement compared to the realtime database.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Daule. I got the same information that collection data will not be downloaded when reading a document.